# Passing a class method as a block to map in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having what's probably a silly problem but I can't for the life of me find anything about whether this can or can't be done.

Basically I'm aware that calling `array.each do(&method)` converts the method into a proc and calls it with each yielded value. The issue I'm having is trying to do the same with a class method.

I've written a `Card` class and want to parse a string with something like this.

```
%w{4S 5D 9H 1C 3S}.map(&Card.safe_parse)
```

I've tried

```
.map(Card.method(:safe_parse).to_proc)
```

and

```
.map(&Card.method(:safe_parse))
```

but nothing is working. Obviously it works with `.map { |x| Card.safe_parse x }` but it feels like there's a cleverer way I'm not seeing and I'm trying to better understand ruby blocks.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you `a.map(&Card.method(:safe_parse))`? That should work fine if `.map { |x| Card.safe_parse x }` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The long way is the most conventional, but the short way is your last example:

```
%w{4S 5D 9H 1C 3S}.map(&Card.method(:safe_parse))
```

This only works if `safe_parse` is a module method, not a mixin method, or in other words you've defined it as `self.safe_parse` or done an `extend self` at the end of the module.

As far as I know it's not possible to use `instance_method` directly on mixin methods since those are missing their instance context.

Comment: ahh I'm the biggest idiot, I didn't think `&Card.method(:safe_parse)` worked but I mustn't have typed it out correctly

Thanks a million!

Comment: It wouldn't work if you'd declared it certain ways, so don't feel too bad. Module methods are a little unusual.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, in preview versions of Ruby 2.7 it had an [experimental feature](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12125) that allowed you to use short notation

```rb
%w{4S 5D 9H 1C 3S}.map(&Card.:safe_parse)
```

The feature [was reverted](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16275) and didn't make into [2.7 release](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/).